# Output besttime for each Track, need some guidance

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table called records which stores every time ever driven on a Track.
I only want to return the best time of each track. And I want to set the TrackId Range. In this example I only want TrackId 2 and 3.

table looks like this

```
TrackId  PlayerId   Time
  1      2         3453
  1      4         6757
  2      7         5478
  3      7         77453
  3      8         66774
```

I'm getting the Names for TrackId and PlayerId from 2 seperate tables called Tracks and Players.

What I want the result to be is:

```
TrackId    PlayerId    Time     
 2             7       5478
 3             8       66774
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT TrackId,
    PlayerId,
    besttime,
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        TrackId,
        PlayerId,
        MIN(Time) AS besttime,
    FROM
        records
    LEFT JOIN tracks ON tracks.Id = records.TrackId
    LEFT JOIN players ON records.PlayerId = players.Id
    WHERE
        tracks.Id >= 2
    GROUP BY
        TrackId
    ORDER BY
        tracks.Id ASC
) X
```

LEFT JOIN is only there to grab the names for the Ids. Not really relevant to my question.

This gives me the best time for each track, however... The PlayerId is wrong, instead of showing player 8, who has the time of 66774, it shows player 7
with a time of 66774. How do I keep the row intact?

Comment: Is it correct, that in fact you only use ```records``` columns ? Why do you even join in the first place then?

Comment: When several tables are involved, it's good programming practice to qualify all columns. (So people don't have to guess.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. It uses a derived table of minimum times per track, and then joins that back to records to get the appropriate `PlayerId` value. An `IN` expression is used to limit the tracks selected:

```
SELECT r.TrackId, r.PlayerId, r.Time
FROM records r
JOIN (SELECT TrackId, MIN(Time) AS Time
      FROM records
      GROUP BY TrackId) m ON m.TrackId = r.TrackId and m.Time = r.Time
WHERE r.TrackId IN (2,3)
ORDER BY r.TrackId
```

Output

```
TrackId PlayerId    Time
2       7           5478
3       8           66774
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rJzdsd5k49u7ukXVm4yTp9/0)

You can add `JOIN`s as necessary to `tracks` and `players` to get their info prior to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think i would approach this more like a filtering problem then a grouping problem as you don't require `GROUP BY/MIN()` to get a minimal per group..

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    records1.TrackId
  , records1.PlayerId
  , records1.Time
FROM 
 records records1 
LEFT JOIN 
 records records2
ON
   records1.TrackId = records2.TrackId # GROUP BY TrackId
 AND
   records1.Time > records2.Time # MIN(Time)
WHERE
   records2.TrackId IS NULL
 AND
   records1.TrackId IN (2,3) 
ORDER BY records1.TrackId
```

**Result**

```
| TrackId | PlayerId | Time  |
| ------- | -------- | ----- |
| 2       | 7        | 5478  |
| 3       | 8        | 66774 |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rJzdsd5k49u7ukXVm4yTp9/2)

**Note**
For performance on larger tables this query really needs to have a `index(TrackId, Time)` atleast..